# How to calculate where an indexed value in a 3d array will be in memory? How to calculate where an indexed value in a char** will be in memory?

Tags: c++

The problem states: Given the following array declarations and indexed accesses, compute the address where the indexed value will be in memory. Assume the array starts at location 200 on a 64-bit computer.

```
a. double d[3][4][4]; d[1][2][3] is at: _________
b. char *n[10]; n[3] is at: _________
```

I know the answers are 416 and 224 (respectively), but I do not understand how those numbers were reached.

For part a, I was told the equation:
address-in-3d-array= start-address + (p * numR * numC + (i * numC) + j) * size-of-type 
(where start address = 200, the numR and numC come from the original array, and the i,j, and p come from the location you are trying to find).

Nothing I do makes this equation come to 416. I have been viewing the order of the array as d[row][column][plane]. Is that incorrect? I have also tried looking at it as d[plane][row][column], but that didn't seem to work either.

For part b, I'm not sure where to start as I thought that as the array is an array of pointers, it's location would be in the heap. I'm not sure how to get 224 from that.

I need to answer these questions by hand, not using code.

Comment: You forgot to try `[plane][column][row]`.

Comment: `n` is not in the heap. There is nothing special about pointers, including whether they are stored in "the heap" or not.

Comment: An array is only on the heap if you allocate it with `new` or `malloc()`. If you declare it like `char *n[10]` you get an array of 10 `char*`s on the stack. So `n[3]` is the third element of this array and should be at start address + 3 * sizeof(char *)

Comment: What are you using for numR and numC?

Comment: Indices are evaluated left-to-right. One counter-intuitive result is that if you want to add an additional dimension, which amounts to creating an array of arrays, you add that new dimension *on the left side:*: An array of three ints is `int arr1d[3];`. 4 of *that* are `int arr2d[4][3];`. If you step through the evaluation of an access like `int i = arr2d[3][2];` it makes sense: You evaluate the first index and obtain the fourth of the four arrays with 3 elements each, whose third element you reach by indexing again with 2. This should also solve your memory layout question.

Comment: sizeof(char*) is well defined for a 64 bit machine; sizeof(double) isn't.  The standard only says the range that must be supported.  I know they want to assume 8 bytes, but there's not a requirement on that at all!  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Answer (score 1):

For this array declaration

```
double d[3][4][4];
```

to calculate the address of the expression

```
d[1][2][3]
```

You can use the following formula

```
reinterpret_cast<double *>( d ) + 1 * 16 + 2 * 4 + 3
```

that is the same (relative to the value of the expression) as

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>( d ) + 27 * sizeof( double )
```

So you can calculate the address like the address of the first element of the array plus the expression `27 * sizeof( double )` where double is equal to 8.

For this array

```
char *n[10];
```

the address of the expression

```
n[3]
```

is

```
reinterpret_cast<char *>( n ) + 3 * sizeof( char * )
```

Answer (score 1):

In words:

Given a generic array *d[s1][s2][s3]* of elements of size *S*, the offset of the *d[x][y][z]* element is

```
[(x * s2 * s3) + (y * s3) + z] * S
```

In the array `double d[3][4][4]`, with `S = sizeof(double) = 8`, the location of `d[1][2][3]` is at offset:

```
[(1 * 4 * 4) + (2 * 4) + 3] * 8 = 216
```

Sum the offset (216) to the start (200) to get 416.

Given a generic array *n[s1]* of elements of size *S*, the offset of the *n[x]* element is

```
x * S
```

In the array `char * n[10]`, with `S = 8` (pointers size on 64bit platforms), the location of `n[3]` is at offset

```
3 * 8 = 24
```

Sum the offset (24) to the start (200) to get 224.

In code:

```
int main()
{
    double d[3][4][4];

    size_t start = 200;

    size_t offset =
          sizeof(d[0])       * 1
        + sizeof(d[0][0])    * 2
        + sizeof(d[0][0][0]) * 3;

    std::cout << start + offset << std::endl; //416 on my machine

    char * n[10];
    offset = 3 * sizeof(char*);

    std::cout << start + offset << std::endl; //224 on every 64bit platforms
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I should have specified that I am meant to calculate these figures by hand.